# View controller file template seems to be gone in Xcode 6

Tags: xcode, xcode6

How do I create an Objective-C view controller for an iOS app in Xcode 6?  In previous iterations, I could click "Objective-C class" and choose to automatically inherit from `UIViewController`. Now the only options are "Objective-C File" and "Header File" which don't allow me to inherit from UIVC.  Any ideas?

If you're downvoting because there's an answer somewhere else please let me know - I couldn't find it myself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click on project > New file > Choose Cocoa Touch Class > Set Subclass of to UIViewController.